# uWSGI touch-reload option doesn't work

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I've tried to user touch-reload option in .ini file and from command line. Both not helps. This is my startup log:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.14 (64bit) on [Wed Nov  2 17:46:38 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) on 05 October 2016 20:03:58
os: Linux-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 24 16:09:20 UTC 2016
current working directory: /home/mutex/crm
detected binary path: /usr/sbin/uwsgi
chdir() to /opt/crm/application
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /opt/crm/sock/uwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.5 (default, Sep 15 2016, 22:37:39)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
added /opt/crm/ to pythonpath.
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x1909850 pid: 20099 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 20099, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 20104, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 20105, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 20106, cores: 1)
```

This is not all messages, I truncated it a bit.
This is my config:

```
[mutex@p401790 crm]$ cat uwsgi.ini 
[uwsgi]
env=PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
env=LANG=en_US.UTF-8
master=0
workers=4
chdir=/opt/crm/application
socket=/opt/crm/sock/uwsgi.sock
pythonpath=/opt/crm
module=runserver
callable=app
logto=/opt/crm/log/uwsgi.log
logformat=[%(ctime)] %(addr) - %(host) %(method) %(uri) %(status) %(msecs)ms
touch-reload=/opt/crm/reload.ini
plugins = python
gid=nginx
uid=nginx
py-autoreload = 1
```

py-autoreload option also doensn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

For these options to work (and, in general, to be able to reload the uWSGI server gracefully) the server must be running with the `master` process mode ([docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html#reloading-the-server)) - so you need to set `master=true` in your `uwsgi.ini`.